# Make a Query Expression ignore the Time and filter only the Date

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, datetime, linq-to-entities

I want write a query expression to return some records filtering on a date range, and ignore the time.

It is possible that the start and end dates will match (results for one day). EF seems to always append the time to the resulting SQL query and this is driving me nuts.

**Is there a way to indicate to ignore the Time component when filtering on a DateTime when using a Query Expression with EF?**

Expression query:

```
searchQuery = searchQuery.Where(currentQuery => currentQuery.Ticket.th_TicketDate >= startDate && currentQuery.Ticket.th_TicketDate <= endDate);
```

Executing this returns 0 results because EF includes the time 00:00:00, like so:

```
Select * from t_TicketHeader
Where th_TicketDate >= '2014-08-01 00:00:00' 
AND th_TicketDate <= '2014-08-01 00:00:00'
```

Whereas if I write and run my own SQL query directly (bump the end date forward a day):

```
Select * from t_TicketHeader
Where th_TicketDate >= '2014-08-01' 
AND th_TicketDate <= '2014-08-02'
```

I retrieve my 2 expected results:

```
th_TicketNumber  th_TicketDate
OT01938332       2014-08-01 06:00:00.000
OT01938333       2014-08-01 06:00:00.000
```

My current solution is to transform my date criteria, pushing the time to the end of the day, but this solution seems a bit *hacky*:

```
startDate = new DateTime(searchCriteria.StartDate.Year, searchCriteria.StartDate.Month, searchCriteria.StartDate.Day);
endDate = new DateTime(searchCriteria.EndDate.Year, searchCriteria.EndDate.Month, searchCriteria.EndDate.Day, 23, 59, 59);
```

Comment: The hacky solutions are often the best for sql datetimes. Your solution included. I see nothing wrong with doing it the way you mentioned.

Comment: how can the sql function work fine, if sql treats start date `2014-08-01` as `2014-08-01 00:00:00`, then the end date should be the same `2014-08-01 00:00:00`, and vice versa

Comment: Good catch, I wrote the dates incorrectly. I clarified. If I bump the end date forward a day, I get my expected result. The confusion lies in that it seems like no matter what, a time is always expected...am I correct in saying this?

Comment: Not sure how sql treats date without time, haven't found any reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this, the key is modifying the end date.

```
var formattedEndDate = endDate.Date.AddDays(1).AddMilliseconds(-1);
searchQuery = searchQuery.Where(currentQuery => 
    currentQuery.Ticket.th_TicketDate >= startDate.Date 
    && currentQuery.Ticket.th_TicketDate <= formattedEndDate);
```

Or

```
var formattedEndDate = endDate.Date.AddDays(1);
searchQuery = searchQuery.Where(currentQuery => 
    currentQuery.Ticket.th_TicketDate >= startDate.Date 
    && currentQuery.Ticket.th_TicketDate < formattedEndDate);
                                     // ^^^ remove the equal sign
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`DbFunctions.TruncateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220142(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: I just tried it and checked with profiler, the `00:00:00` is still appear, but there is another sql function appear, this might work, `(convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), @p__linq__0, 102) ,  102))`

Comment: Yes, I also gave this a whirl and had no luck.